# Can't change office 2016 language to English

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, language

Right now, the languae on all of my office applications is Hebrew, and I can't set it to English. In Options -> Language, my display language is set to match the Microsoft Windows language (which is English), but for some reason it doesn't match it. I also don't have an option of installing new display languages. My office version is Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

This is how my language options look on excel:
[image: 1]
1 - This says "Other display languages", and it's empty for all office applications.

2 - Match "Microsoft Windows" is first priority, but It's still not in English.

Comment: [You may refer this,,,](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/install-the-language-accessory-packs-for-office-2016-a9ce8027-3143-b032-8006-53e842828c9d#:~:text=Open%20any%20Office%20program%2C%20click,your%20changes%20can%20take%20effect.) ,,, or [this one even](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't download the Office language pack, you can refer to this article:

https://www.repairwin.com/download-office-2016-language-packs/